# bash command substitution: find command with wildcard in single quotes

Tags: bash, quotes, command-substitution

I want to dynamically construct a "find" command and see whether it returns anything.

This is the minimised example. In a directory containing files,

```
find . -name '*'
```

of course returns the files. But

```
VAR="find . -name '*'"
$VAR
```

returns nothing. Looks like a problem of interpretation of quotes. But why?

(The real case is that I want to see whether files with a certain prefix exist. So I intended to use `-name '${MYPREFIX}*'`, capture the output within `$()`, and test whether the resulting string is empty.)

Apologies if this is trivial. I did spend time to find the answer, but all cases I found were somehow different. Usually, the problem is the shell expanding the wildcard when the find command should do it. Here, the shell does not do any premature expansion, but neither does find, maybe because find receives literal quotes? Thanks for any insight.

Comment: The single quote is for preventing the shell from expanding the wildcards, but they're not part of the `find` command proper, and the reason it stopped working is that you are now instructing `find` to look only for files whose name begins and ends with a single quote. `eval` basically just happens to work here, but the real solution is to fix the quoting. However, see also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eval $VAR
```

The `eval` will reinterpret the value of `$VAR` as a command with arguments.

Be wary: `eval` is a powerful but dangerous mechanism.

Comment: `echo $VAR` is often a wise precursor to `eval $VAR`. :-)

Comment: I thought I knew `eval`, but didn't realise it might be necessary within `$()`. Both your answer and kev's solve my problem. Thank you!

Comment: "`eval` is dangerous" - nah, not more dangerous than any other shell scripting stuff

Answer (score 1):

I recommend against using `eval` whenever possible.  In this case, if you really need to store the command in a variable before executing it, I'd recommend using an array and then invoking it as `"${cmd_array[@]}"`:

```
var=(find . -name "${prefix}*")  # This stores the elements of the command as an array
result=$("${var[@]}")  # This executes the command and stores its output in $result
```

Note that you can also construct the find command dynamically:

```
patterns=()  # start with an empty list of patterns
for prefix in $prefix_list; do
    patterns+=(-o -name "${prefix}*")  # add each prefix to a list of find patterns
done
patterns=("${patterns[@]:1}") # Use array slicing to remove the first "-o"
result=$(find . "${patterns[@]}")
```

Depending on how you use it, it might also help to wrap the find command in a bash function:

```
find_prefix() {
    find . -name "${1}*"
}
result=$(find_prefix "$prefix")
```